# MIPS difference between two integers in array

Tags: mips

I need to build a program (hard-code) in MIPS that gets an array of 10 integers and finds the difference between two nearby numbers in the array. This is what I have build:

```
    .data
array:      .word       23,-2,45,67,89,12,-100,0,120,6
arrend: 

comma: .asciiz ", "

    # array = {23,-2,45,67,89,12,-100,0,120,6}
    # Algorithm being implemented to find the difference between nearby elements of the array
    # difference = 0 (use $t0 for difference)
    # loop i = 0 to length-1 do (use $t1 for i)
    # difference = array[i]-array[i+1]
    # end loop (use $t3 for base addr. of array)

    # registers:
    #   t0 -- difference
    #
    #   t3 -- pointer to current array element (e.g. arrptr)
    #   t2 -- pointer to end of array
    # 
    #   t4 -- current value fetched from array (i)
    #   t5 -- value fetched from array (i+1)

    .text

main:
    li      $t0,0                   # difference = 0

    la      $t3,array               # load base addr. of array
    la      $t2,arrend              # load address of array end
    j       test 

loop:
    lw      $t4,0($t3)              # load array[i]
    addi    $t3,$t3,4               # increment array pointer
    lw      $t5,0($t3)              # load array[i+1]   
    sub     $t0, $t4, $t5           # the difference of two nearby elements

    # print value of difference
    li      $v0,1
    addi    $a0,$t0,0
    syscall

    # print comma
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,comma
    syscall

test:
    blt     $t3,$t2,loop            # more to do? if yes, loop
```

the output should be : 
`25, -47, -22, -22, 77, 112, -100, -120, 114,`

but I get the output `25, -47, -22, -22, 77, 112, -100, -120, 114, -8230,`

I found out if I change `la $t2,arrend` to `la $t2,0x10010024`, it will work, but I don't know how to write it in the code.

furthermore, how can I improve my code?

Comment: #ממן באוניברסיטה הפתוחה

Answer (score 0):

Ok... So, you are iterating one more time then you need... Just sub 1 from t2 right after you assign the end pointer of the array.

It's also called [bufferoverflow](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).